# How to access web server running in windows like elasticsearch from wsl?

Tags: elasticsearch, wsl-2

I run an elasticseach server in windows, and I want to access is by wsl2. I followed the doc of wsl2 and operate like this:

```sh
cat cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.18.32.1
```

and then

```
curl -XGET "172.18.32.1:9200"
```

but timeout.

In windows the elasticsearch runs normally

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JiaD.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware that one of the main criteria for questions on this site is that they be regarding *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* Your question would likely be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com), but please be sure to familiarize yourself with that site's rules for posting as well.  I'd really recommend deleting it here and moving it over to one of the other sites before the mods close it.  It won't count "against" your rep if you do it yourself before downvotes.

Comment: Give me a reply comment here with an @mention when you move it, and I'll try to provide some input on the Super User question.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's a windows firewall issue. also make sure **elasticsearch.yml** has this setting

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/19Dvu.png